# Rounding down decimal numbers in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I read all rounding functions of T-SQL like `Round`, `Floor`, and `Ceil`, but none of them has rounded down decimal numbers correctly for me.

I have 2 questions:

1. How to round down a decimal number (`3.69` ==> `3.5`)?
2. How to round up the last 3 digits of an integer (e.g. `142600` ==> `143000`)?

Comment: You should write udf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** `select CAST(FLOOR(2 * 3.69) / 2 AS decimal(2, 1))` handles the first case - courtesy of an [answer to a similar question on SQL Server Forums](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=183943), which I adapted and quickly checked.

Note that if the numbers you are rounding to the nearest `0.5` could be bigger (e.g. `333.69` => `333.5`), be sure to specify more `decimal` precision when you cast (e.g. `select CAST(FLOOR(2 * 3.69) / 2 AS decimal(10, 1))`), or you could get an overflow error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

Extra precision will not affect the bottom-line result (i.e. `select CAST(FLOOR(2 * 3.69) / 2 AS decimal(10, 1))` and `select CAST(FLOOR(2 * 3.69) / 2 AS decimal(2, 1))` both yield `3.5`); but it is wasteful if the numbers you are rounding will always be smaller.

Online references with examples are available for T-SQL [`FLOOR`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), [`CAST`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), and [`decimal`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to help.

**2)** `select ROUND(142600, -3)` handles the second case.

A similar online reference is available for T-SQL [`ROUND`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks J0e3gan.It Works Correctly!

Answer (score 1):

As per @J0e3gan 's anwser, [Sql Server's Round](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) allows rounding to the nearest powers of 10 using the `length` parameter, where length is `10^(-length)`, e.g.

```
length = 0 : 10 ^ 0 = nearest 1
length = 3 : 10 ^ -3 = nearest .001
length = -3 : 10 ^ 3 = nearest 1000
```

etc

However, in general, with a simple 1-based rounding function - e.g. (Sql Round with Length=0) to round to an arbitrary value of "nearest N" - with the formula:

```
round(X / N) * N
```

e.g. nearest 100

```
select round(12345 / 100.0, 0) * 100.0 -- 12300
select round(-9876 / 100.0, 0) * 100.0 -- -9900
select round(-9849 / 100.0, 0) * 100.0 -- -9800
```

... Nearest 0.5

```
select round(5.123 / 0.5, 0) * 0.5 -- 5.000
select round(6.499 / 0.5, 0) * 0.5 -- 6.500
select round(-4.499 / 0.5, 0) * 0.5 -- -4.50
```

... Nearest 0.02

```
select round(5.123 / .02, 0) * .02 -- 5.12
select round(-9.871 / .02, 0) * .02 -- -9.88
```

etc

Remember that the type used for the divisors must be numeric / decimal or float.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle/PLSQL `FLOOR` function returns the largest integer value that is equal to or less than a number.
eg:

```
FLOOR(7.9)
Result: 7

FLOOR(30.29)
Result: 30

FLOOR(-7.9)
Result: -8
```