# Rounding up and down of numbers with specific decimal points

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, floor, ceil

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to find rounding up and down values with specific decimal points as shown as below:

**For Example:**

1. If my Value is **1.27845** and I want the answer with 2 decimal places then my answer should be

   1. **Rounding UP: 1.28**
   2. **Rounding Down: 1.27**
2. If my Value is **33.33333** and I want the answer with 2 decimal places then my answer should be

   1. **Rounding UP: 33.34**
   2. **Rounding Down: 33.33**
3. If my Value is **1.27845** and I want the answer with 3 decimal places then my answer should be

   1. **Rounding UP: 1.279**
   2. **Rounding Down: 1.278**
4. If my Value is **33.33333** and I want the answer with 3 decimal places then my answer should be

   1. **Rounding UP: 33.334**
   2. **Rounding Down: 33.333**

I want common solution for all cases. 
Thanks...

Comment: Now that we know what you want please share with us what you have already tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding down decimal numbers in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072136/rounding-down-decimal-numbers-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @PM77-1 I had tried `ROUND()`, Convert to decimal, Ceiling and floor function to do this but I didn't find full solution of my problem

Comment: @PM77-1 Rounding off not resolve my problem fully. It can be used in some case but I want full solution of my problem. I had tried that before.

Comment: @PM77-1 It's not a duplicate first read my question fully and try all problem which I had written, then decide that it is duplicate or not

Comment: Please explain why [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21072460/2055998) is not acceptable.

Comment: Your number **3** is wrong, unless you have **your own** definitions what rounding *up* and *down* means. In such case, provide your definitions and do not expect us to guess.

Comment: @PM77-1 This is what I want in my case in procedure. So I want to build user defined  function to solve this problem. But I want to write the function in optimized manner

Comment: I strongly suggest that you spell out the **rule** that your four examples follow.

Comment: How can there be a common solution if u mention as "iwant answer in 2 or 3 or ....".surely u must combine statements as the answer suggests according to your definition of rounding.

Comment: @SaharshShah I could post my answer keep on getting this error 'an error occurred submitting the answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could could use the following "offset" together with FLOOR and CEILING

```
DECLARE 
    @digit int = 2,
    @value decimal(10,5)=1.27845
DECLARE
    @calc_scale int = POWER(10,@digit)

SELECT 
    CAST(FLOOR (@value * @calc_scale)/@calc_scale AS DECIMAL(10,5)) as down,
    CAST(CEILING (@value * @calc_scale)/@calc_scale AS DECIMAL(10,5)) as up
```

However, the target data type would always be as specified in the query (e.g. a <s>precision</s> edit: scale of 5 in the example above).
You can't change the number of digits in the output dynamically, since this scale depends on the data type of the variable. You could mess around with a conversion to a VARCHAR data type and trim the unwanted digits, but I strongly vote against it.

If you need to display only the significant number of digits, I recommend to trim it at the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I Couldn'd add my code keep on getting this error "an error occurred submitting the answer" so added as picture